# Dynamic Programming Problem: Minimizing A Path Through Array

Tags: java, algorithm, search, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a problem right now where we are provided with a 1D array of values, and must find the path from the first index to the last index that sums to the smallest sum. The only restrictions are that if you go forward, the distance you go must be 1 more than the last "jump", while if you go backwards, you must go the same distance as the last "jump". For instance, given an array `int[] values = new int[]{4, 10, 30, 1, 6}`, you need to find the path that gets you from position 0 (4) to position 4 (6) that sums up to the smallest amount. The starting indice is not counted, thus, if I go from `values[0]` to `values[1]` (which is the only possible starting move), my running total at that point would be 10. From there, I either have the choice to "jump" back the same distance (to `values[0]`), or "jump" one distance longer than my last jump, which would then be 1+1=2, so jump from `values[1]` to `values[3]`.

I'm really new to dynamic programming and attempted a solution that went something like this

```
    public static int smallestCalc(int[] values, int prevJump, int pos, int runTot) {
        while (pos != penal.length) {
            int forwards = 600;
            int backwards = 600;
            try {
                backwards = penal[pos - prevJump];
            } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            try {
                forwards = penal[pos + prevJump+1];
            } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            int min = Math.min(forwards,backwards);
            if (min == backwards) {
                pos -= prevJump;
            } else {
                pos += prevJump + 1;
                prevJump ++;
            }
            runTot+=min;
            smallestCalc(values, prevJump, pos, runTot);
        }
        return runTot;
    }
```

However, I recognize that I'm not actually making use of a dynamic programming table here, but I'm not exactly sure what I would store inside that I need to "remember" across calculations, or how I could even utilize it in calculations. From what I see, it appears that I basically have to make a recursive function that evaluates all possible jump distances from an index, store them, and then traverse through the DP table to find the smallest amount? Should I be starting from the last index or the first index of the array to limit possible moves? I watched this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBRtnuxg-gU&list=PLrmLmBdmIlpsHaNTPP_jHHDx_os9ItYXr&index=23&ab_channel=TusharRoy-CodingMadeSimple), and understood the premise, but it seems much more applicable to his 2D Array than anything I have. Any amount of guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is solved with dynamic programming? The changing jump length makes it difficult. Also it could be best to make several jumps backwards before going forward again.

Comment: Agree with the above. Not certain if my conclusion is correct, but problems with optimal solutions that consist of returning to visited states can't be solved with simple dynamic programming. Here, it may optimal to re-visit already seen positions, as it may be necessary to re-adjust the jump counter in order to reach some element (for example, it can be best to visit index 0 twice to reach index 3: `0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 0 -> 3`. The video solution can use dp because there's no way to re-visit already seen states in the matrix. I'm thinking a priority queue + bfs would be the way to go here.

Comment: @maraca what do you make of Stark's solution below?

Comment: @Cheesehead in my opinion it's just trying all possibilities with memoisation. I really doubt that the implementation is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a 2D DP problem.

dp(i, j) represents the minimum sum required to reach last index from index i and minimum jump allowed of size j.
Let's say you are at index i in the array. Then you can either go to index i-j+1 or index i+j.

So,

```
int recur(int values[], int i, int j){
    // base case. Here n is size of values array
    if(i==n-1)
        return 0;
    
    if(dp[i][j] != -1){
    /* here -1 is taken as to mark never calculated state of dp. 
    If the values[] array also contains negative values then you need to change it to 
    something appropriate.
    */
        return dp[i][j];
    }
    int a = INT_MAX;
    int b = a;
    if(i>0 && (i-j+1)>=0)
        a = values[i-j + 1] + recur(values, i-j+1, j);
    if(i+j < n)
        b = values[i+j] + recur(values, i+j, j+1);
    return dp[i][j] = min(a, b);
}
```

Time and space complexity O(n * n).

**Edit:**
Initial function call is `recur(values, 0, 1)`.

I know that the tag of this question is java but I do competitive programming in c++ only. Here I have [full working code](https://ideone.com/i35Dd0) if you want in c++.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion, but as final output, I just get whatever I set the INT_MAX as. The logic and everything makes sense to me, but I am unsure where the breakdown is. We were told that max value of any slot in `values[]` would be 499, so I set 500 as my INT_MAX. Also, should any instances of `i-j+1` actually be (i-(j+1))?

Comment: Also, given that I would be starting at position 0 and could only do a jump forward, should I first call recur(values, 0, 1) to start everything?

Comment: @Cheesehead Yes you should call the function as `recur(values, 0, 1)`. And `i-j+1` is actually `i-(j-1)`. Let's say you are at index `i` and size `j`. You must have reached here using a jump of size `j-1` because then only you are allowed to make a jump of size `j-1 + 1` from index `i`. So, if you wish to go back(if possible) instead of moving forward then you should make a jump of size `j-1` and the index you would reach is `(i - (j-1)) = i-j+1`.

Comment: Another thing to be taken care of is initialization of the dp matrix. Generally, in problems where array values >= 0 and we are required to only find min/max of sum of some of the values, we use -1 as the initialization because we know for sure that sum of positive values can never reach -1 and if `dp[i][j] = -1`, it means this state has not been calculated and we need to recursively find the solution of this state as well.

I guess, in your case the elements of the values array can be negative as well and if you don't know any bounds for it, just use an unordered_map for storing dp values.

Comment: Now, about the INT_MAX thing. This is used as an identity element for min function. Because the minimum of anything with this is always the other number. Ideally, this is positive infinity but for practical purposes this number should be more than the maximum answer possible in any of the test cases. 

The size of array (n) is typically 10^5 and as you told that elements of array values does not exceed 499, you can take INT_MAX to be `(10^5) * 500)`.

I ran the code for the test case:
`int[] values = new int[]{4, 10, 30, 1, 6}` and I got 27 as the output which is the minimum cost.